# Add word/string to multiple feature classes using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, feature-class, rename

I am using ArcGIS Pro 3.

I have `31` `feature classes` in a `gdb` and I would like to add a word/string at the end of each feature class's name. For example, for feature class `A` I would like to add `_TREES` to its name so it would end up like `A_TREES` and so on for the rest of the 31 features classes.

I did find the `rename` tool which I am running in batch. After running the tool, I start getting the following error in a loop meaning the messages keep coming and I have force stop the tool.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your title includes the term "simultaneously," why do you have a requirement to do it simultaneously?  Most batch tools are serial and not parallel, so they do not meet a "simultaneously" requirement.

Comment: @bixb0012, please feel free to edit the title to add something more appropriate than `simultaneously` as English is not my first language.

Comment: You can do this using arcpy: [List them](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/functions/listfeatureclasses.htm), manipulate the string, [rename](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/tool-reference/data-management/rename.htm)

Comment: @BERA, thank you, what about using the `rename` tool in batch?

Comment: @SonofaBeach yes, I did run it as shown in the screenshot. And the tool starts giving errors that `file` is either not available or not supported even though I did add that file  as one of the inputs as shown in the image above. The errors then starting running in a loop, so I have to stop it. Once I stop it, only one file `COCONUT_CREEK` gets renamed to `COCONUT_CREEK_TREES`.

Comment: @SonofaBeach, so I guess I am not writing the output data element correctly, thus how can I fix it?

Comment: @SonofaBeach sure thing, will do it tomorrow once I am at my office, cheers.

Comment: @SonofaBeach, please see the updated question.

Comment: Could you post the first few messages also - as text, NOT as an image.  You can select and copy them from the Messages tab in that window.  Scroll to the top and copy everything up to, and including, the first error.

Comment: The error messages are pretty straight forward, the tool doesn't see/find the data set in the path it is looking for it to be located.  Have you verified `C:\LiDAR\dummy.gdb\COCONUT_CREEK` exists?  Have you already renamed it by chance in a previous attempt at running batch rename?